# Send an email when records are added to Firebase database

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to send an email to the signed user with the data that was added by the user to the Firebase database. I am using AngularJS UI. Is there are Firebase module which will trigger email with the data being added to the signed user.

Thanks, Rajesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should look into [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).  This will let you write [database triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) that run on Google servers that can act whenever data in your database changes.  There is plenty of [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) the illustrates some of the many things you can do, including one specific example that shows how to [send email in response to a change in the database](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/email-confirmation).